# How to define the type of an axios error response

Tags: node.js, axios

i am making a call to an api. There are 2 types of responses i can receive from axios `response.data`. If it's 200. `IIndustryGroupList` if its another error like 400. `IAPIErrorResponse`

```
export const GetIndustry = async () => {
    const base = Config.api_url;
    const endpoint = "/api/industry";
    const url = base + endpoint;

    try {
        const response = await HttpClient.get<IIndustryGroupList[]>(url, options);
        return [response, null] as const;
    } catch (err: any) {
        // here we can receive the axios response for a 400.
        return [null, err.response] as const;
    }
};
```

In the catch statement, when a 400 response is received i want to define the return response to be of type `IAPIErrorResponse`. more specifically `axios.response.data` should be of type `IAPIErrorResponse`

[image]

**usage**

```
const [response, error] = await GetIndustry();

// response.data of type IIndustryGroupList
// error.data of type IAPIErrorResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not reealy sure of what you are trying to achieve, but this will definitely give you the means to reach what you want:

```
import axios, {
  AxiosRequestConfig,
  AxiosResponse,
} from 'axios';

type IIndustryGroupList = {
  somedata: string[]
}

type IAPIErrorDATA = {
  someerrorobject: object
}

type IAPIErrorResponse = {
  message: string,
  status: 400,
  data: IAPIErrorDATA
}

type ObjectWithProperty<P extends string> = {
  [K in P]: unknown
} & {
  [key: string]: unknown
}

const Config = {
  api_url: 'http://example.com',
};

/**
 *  Asserts that an object has a given property
 * @param value
 * @param property
 * @returns
 */
const objHasProperty = <P extends string>(
  value: unknown,
  property: P,
): value is ObjectWithProperty<P> => {
  if (typeof value !== 'object' || value === null) return false;
  if (property in value) return true;
  return false;
};

/**
 * Checks if an object is of `IAPIErrorResponse` type
 * @param response
 * @returns
 */
const isIAPIErrorResponse = (
  response: unknown,
): response is IAPIErrorResponse => {
  if (
    typeof response !== 'object'
    || response === null
  ) return false;

  if (
    objHasProperty(response, 'status')
    && objHasProperty(response, 'data')
    && response.status === 400
    // AND SOME OTHER CHECKS THAT ASSERT
    // YOUR OBJECT IS OF TYPE IAPIRESPONSE
  ) return true;

  return false;
};

/**
 * The HTTP client
 */
const HttpClient = {
  async get<T>(
    url: string,
    options: AxiosRequestConfig,
  ) {
    return axios.get<T>(url, options);
  },
};

/**
 * Your function
 * @returns
 */
export const GetIndustry = async (): Promise<
  [AxiosResponse<IIndustryGroupList[], any>, null]
| [null, IAPIErrorResponse]
> => {
  const base = Config.api_url;
  const endpoint = '/api/industry';
  const url = base + endpoint;
  const options = {};

  try {
    const response = await HttpClient.get<IIndustryGroupList[]>(
      url,
      options,
    );

    return [response, null];
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    if (
      objHasProperty(err, 'reponse')
      && isIAPIErrorResponse(err.response)
    ) return [null, err.response];

    const errMsg = `Unknown error${
      objHasProperty(err, 'message')
        ? `: ${err.message}.`
        : '.'
    }`;
    throw new Error(errMsg);
  }
};

(async () => {
  const [response, error] = await GetIndustry();
  if (error) {
    const r = response;
    // Here response is of type null
    const e = error;
    // And error is of type IAPIErrorResponse
    const { data } = error;
    // HERE! Data is of type IAPIErrorDATA
  } else {
    const { data } = response;
    // Here data is of type IIndustryGroupList[]
    const e = error;
    // And error is of type null
  }
})();
```

[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZwDRwN4FgBQccAgiugEoCmAjgK6VowDCEAdgGbADmGBRpqNFTSRWaSr3wBfOOygQQcAOTJBSgNwECMAJ5hKcAJKHWAE1qMoOgOLzaYADLBGcALw4+cNAsqmEMBAAuLxgoYFYuAG0AXQIpLXxdfSNiAAVDAFEoeSgAEWIAFWI3D0IvH0ps6AgAIwArSgBjGGDahua4hKSDQzTMqqhhUXESvDKQBjQELkpgy3CeT0Z-C2CAFgAGDckiPwDg3vSsnPyizvxtPQMAeXqmmAB1YBgAC1T5fVgdAB5UuEokDBKGY0CEwhEAHyjTyRADScHCcFS0WCtFYAGtWBAAO6sOJwABkpSIkXRlB0c1CCxRcDRmJxeOkCUabBcLA43GhZQQYGAAH1aFAADbBJQvGAwMCBAD00oBCHAQsoADoWSAlJIpJoLvhpQAqPV8PX8NDiWCg17+RCsOBte5wF4IUEIOBcYAAN2BcDAH0quiNcAAAmAEFAFXB3QghfQA8HQ+GfRBPv7CMbA1BKDBBWIjdKCCyxPA2gAJJ3vJN+nQlX7-QHA0yg+aQgAUnkj0dmtIxWNxO29vq+wVSkgAlMF2-QEaDbu1Hs83gPdL8oa4oWMiMB2HBm90IFuJwYAISudxKO3NJRwAA+V4jUcnJ-crFoQqFI7gGazUBt7Cj4m1G5bs2ibJlWiIHu+n7ZnAoT0ABH6ZtBv5Cv+cTagQ+qGqmcBMC8TToqCm7WradzNFOtpbgABoc-Q5EMrKUJRMFXLGIZhooGYiAxsZQd+aC5vmrLwM4NHHNA9FiAY7itmUnHDJ2dI9qwo7BHJDHkaJAwSSMq7EgiQGeEQu5bmpklwMep7njASiGdet6mTpJ5wM+r6eJBiHfrIf6UOhZRETJRBECWZaLjozYORIyjLFmaBKCOtkEkSwVoOWoHhQw8lYEoewIHFCVEhFyrRRYbhOZsGy2bKJAAHK5HAADK1wALIZHA1wFMWGTkDhnVMLC9VwB1hQkPV9VdQUlXSnAACa1wAKrddcABCABSGRMAURgDdcABig3TakrU0eQGT1ak1zVWNbkIV+NqwT5CRELxP7edqWoJJhAYFHhcDFgUBR-I0QrAMCMACfgBYuMWEpgEwwOg1yRBOjorCNK6mbfAUEIBYFgoimCCx9kFYAwKgYjBAIFA0PQjDspwixlO+66Bc9iBkGgyozDAmPY3jWBJqTrIjvBUiar5n3YdNECCrIaLNGTPEeTmqZ5vgAKQLAcCQ-A1iZiY5iWFW7jI6j25jki8ggM4lDfDClNCBlDHfMYZgWKENh2I4zgwDEWAIKwOgQlgLlCrE+C3pEIdYJpdGO5JYcrmunja3ANROlJOFsPTyo8vyePwSn9aQOE8CntKufSuEBvuxoydCbSwolGnIwANT-GYxesDABf1wLZOgu42DvTqRlWHpRApxFJQINiCDPL9MNwyDXecxjLvV1YtjS17jAxNjtlEHzB+2iT-dE3AwuPSzStwJEEXBy+oci1r-iNC826VFAqLdgyTO2f5x9kqpUrM2T+WUMzyTymUQKhIiQiT6GJQYcdxCgOyMqCK8VoEXxutBSOj8sCf3Qcgyg0RfIwMLtkJqaAuAlEonNH+uJ-gDAACTMxgUA0KqCoBZQmKaaYlAoEwJgQAfjgJRYIrDCG8KmDMKQypKLHyIKKZUNksFSEovBIyLx5DYmcpQXRiCuFUK4JfMo8RpC+WbCbNGzZ3y6WZinO+xCCEDGiNPWe89dYwH1m7Kwtj4L+U-tAP+WDJ4lAipouAVViyVAMFPZwFFmLJBDrZQuJQglQEiVVYgZgmE5HInuJJPQEFaWIak+u2A4A5TgDIdwGSslTU6idQ8cBcj+BdAkwp3QUhHAGKcYgngZCUBQgYNhWsKlVPaTU8JxCGm-ViZMgIBStzdPXr4j228nC7zDuQ+uGd6mTRILkjJyyinOUfoMuII5-FAA)

Comment: `axios.get` has a genertic type for its return response `get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>): Promise<R>;` But when it throws an error where the response received from the api is 400. I want to to set the return type of that error `err.response.data` just like i can set the return type of `response.data`

I hope thats clear i dont want you to waste time implementing a complicated solution

Comment: Well than that is exactly what I did.

Comment: I edited it so it is more clear. Check the typings at the last lines

Comment: Didn't this work for you?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in following way:

```
const response = await HttpClient.get<IIndustryGroupList[] | IAPIErrorResponse>(url, options);
```

Comment: I don't think thats right, that would make `response` be of type `IIndustryGroupList` OR `IAPIErrorResponse` which is not what im asking.